# rename and delete a file in cpp

Tags: c++, rename

I'm working on phone book project in delete section of the project i have a problem; here is my delete section code:

```
        void pbook::del(){
    cout<<"Enter Id(Be sure to Enter with #) or a full info of a Contact to Delete:"<<endl;
    string ds,line,deltemp;
    cin>>ds;
    ifstream pb("pb.gh");
    while(getline(pb,line)){
    if (line.find(ds) != string::npos) {    
    deltemp=line;
    continue;
        }
        else{
            fstream pbtemp("pbtemp.gh",ios::app);
            pbtemp<<line<<endl;
        }

    }
    cout<<deltemp<<" was successfully deleted !";
    }
```

I'm trying to delete general phone book file after writing all contacts except deleted one to bptemp.gh but `remove("pb.gh")` Doesn't do anything! and I thought changing `ifstream pb("pb.gh");` to `fstream pb("pb.gh");` would help but after doing that "pbtemp.gh" will not be generated!
Please help me to remove "pb.gh" and rename "pbtemp.gh" to "pb.gh".
Regards

Comment: My guess is, you are trying to delete the file while it's still held open by `pb`. Close the stream first.

Comment: C++ does not provide any standard means to delete a file currently.  It should be available in the next release though: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem

Comment: @NathanOliver What about `remove()`?

Comment: Ah.  I didn't see that.  Can you show how you use the code with `remove`?  Also note that it will not do anything if the file is open on windows and it is implementation defined what it does on POSIX systems.

Answer (score 0):

First, remove(const char*) return a error code. Check it and you will know what happen. Second, why do you not use a c++ library for it instead of c function? Take a look on filesystem library (since c++17)